# Is this quote from Lenin: "Make them swallow the word, they will swallow the thing"?

Tags: history, politics, quotes

[Éric Zemmour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89ric_Zemmour), the far-right probable candidate for the 2022 French presidential election said  (in his book *La France n'a pas dit son dernier mot* but also in many meetings, [example](https://artofuss.blog/2021/02/27/eric-zemmour-islamo-gauchisme-le-mot-et-la-chose/)) that Lenin has said:

In French: *"Faites-leur manger le mot, ils avaleront la chose"* or *"Faites-leur avaler le mot, ils avaleront la chose."*

Translated into English: "Make them swallow the word, they will swallow the thing."*

I cannot find any reference.  Did Lenin or somebody else really say something similar?

Comment: Irrelevant to your actual question, but is the quote grammatically correct French? My French is rusty but the 'leur' looks off to me.

Comment: Translating Lenin into French and then translating what a French person says about it into English is fraught with difficulty. I'm not sure if there is a French idiom there, but in English: "[to eat one's words](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/eat+one%27s+words)" means "to retract what one has said". OTOH in English "to swallow" means "to believe" in some contexts.

Comment: Duplicate? [Did Lenin say "a lie told often enough becomes the truth"?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/32926/did-lenin-say-a-lie-told-often-enough-becomes-the-truth)

Comment: @quarague Yes it is grammatically correct, I'm a French native speaker.

Comment: @WeatherVane I agree, l'm removing the "make them eat the word" as an English translation to avoid confusion.

Comment: Perhaps a French speaker could explain what this *means* in French, rather than a literal translation, so we can compare to the duplicate more easily?

Comment: @Oddthinking French speaker here, same as in English, avaler ("to swallow") in the sense "to believe". In French, "to swallow" in the sense "to believe" exists although not frequent, but in French as well "to swallow a word/ a thing" is not common at all and is not a French idiom.

Comment: @Oddthinking It means (here): if they accept the word proscription, they accept the concept the Bolsheviks intended this to mean (ie: the politics; as EZ interprets this: 'use woke terminology and vecome thru that a lefty'). There are a few instances where VIL's word are directly translated from Russian into this 'swallow' as in 'accept'…

Comment: So, it means if they accept the definition of a word, they will believe in the concept the word describes?

Comment: Sounds like [the hypothesis of linguistic relativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_relativity).

Comment: @Oddthinking Almost, but too weak. Whether indeed from VIL or not, _here_ it means that EZ at least half subscribes to this idea, as a viable strategy his political adversaries believe in (by extension he himself too to a degree), with the added notion that it's indeed the _intended/pro-scribed_ concept & behavioural consequences with it, in thoughts, words & deeds. (Which he describes as at the same wrong (ahmhm…) plus 'dangerous' _&_ 'not working' (huh?). I'd say agreeing with Nat: a Schoedinger's cat of Sapir-Whorf's… ). It's not exactly an old Klingon proverb.